# Intergrating xcode profiler with calabash testing framework

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, calabash

I want to test my iOS app along with a memory profiler. I hope to use XCode  inbuilt memory profiler with Calabash testing tool. But I can't run both at once. What I want is to integrate the both and analyze memory usage while testing the app. If calabash can't do this I want to know atleast XCode Automation tool can integrate with the XCode memory profiler.

can someone help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to use Calabash tool and Allocations tool together. But I found a way to use Allocations tool and Automation tool together. In XCode profiler first choose Automation tool and then click library tool in the tool bar. After that add the tools you need(In this case Allocations tool)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but the results are pretty hard to understand.  I use this to track down leaks in the Calabash iOS Server.

You'll need an Automation + Leaks/Allocations template and you'll need to use the TEMPLATE environment variable.

The next time I use this technique, I will generate a document that describes the process.